# Write Portion of an Image to File

Tags: c, opencv

While I can write a whole image to a file with

```
cvSaveImage("image.png", img);
```

how can I write only a given rectangle from the image I'm working on to a file?

Comment: Have you tried setting the image ROI with cvSetImageROI(img,roi)?

Comment: @LukeMorgan Actually, I didn't know about it. Thanks, you should have posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `Mat` constructor:

```
Mat(const Mat& m, const Rect& roi);
```

So just use it!

Or if you use `c` (not `c++`) interface than you have to set ROI (Region Of Interest):

http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_(ROI)/

Your code should look like this:

```
cvSetImageROI(img, rect);//rect is a ROI
cvSaveImage("image.png", img);
```

If you want to work again with full image than you have to reset ROI:

```
cvResetImageROI( IplImage* img )
```

Comment: he is using the C interface, not the C++ one